# Website changes font-size of div upon changing its display property (only on mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing my own site as a hobby (any html/css/js I know is self taught), but I've run into a issue that I can't seem to really understand (and thus I don't know how to fix it). I can't handle/fix this by myself unfortunately.

I tried taking away as much unneeded code as I could, reducing the site to the bare minimum where it still exhibits the unwanted behavior. I'm sorry for amateurish/hacky code, I'm not doing this professionally after all.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/IDoNotTrustYourSite/tg7y63ad/25/) is a jsfiddle showing the code. It exhibits my wanted behavior: Click on any of the "Folders" and it expands and shows the "content". So far, so good.

If I now load the exact same code onto a site (I'm using netlify here), it still behaves as I want it to: [Netlify link](https://waxfax.netlify.app/)

If however I access it on a mobile browser (for reference I tried it on Google Chrome, Firefox and Brave browsers, all on Android) I get some behavior that I don't want:

If I expand one Folder, it works as intended, but if I expand the second folder as well the Folder name and its contents seem to change font size (they get noticeably bigger). If I close the normal one and reopen it it also changes size. For reference,

[image: Picture of Site]

this is what it looks like.
It almost seems like me switching the display property to `block` changes the font size to something else, but I only defined one font size in the whole css.

I really don't know why this happens and I'd appreciate any help that explains it or points me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Edit: I managed to contact a third party who tried the site on their phone (iOS) and there the site did not exhibit the same weird/unwanted behavior. I'm not sure what exactly to do with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have finally found a working solution to this weird and unexpected behavior. In your CSS, in the `body` section, add the following rules:

```
  font-size-adjust: none;
  text-size-adjust: none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Those rules do not really have wide-spread support, apparently, and might change or their support get dropped at some point. One works only for Firefox, the other only for Chromium-based browsers, and yet another seems necessary for legacy Chromium-based. See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust
- https://caniuse.com/?search=font-size-adjust
- https://caniuse.com/?search=text-size-adjust

Only with all three of those rules did I successfully prevent this font scaling for mobile Chromium, mobile Firefox Quantum (the old Firefox <=68 was not affected), both on Android, and for Chromium mobile mode on a Linux desktop. At least as far as my tests indicate.

Although I still fail to understand how and why such a rule would even be necessary: There definitely is no other conflicting rule in your example to affect rendered font size. My *very* wild guess would be that, under certain circumstances, some mobile browsers do not apply `font-size` rules correctly to hidden elements, causing this obscure cascaded font scaling.

Comment: I can't put into words how thankful I am to you! Upon my testing it behaves as expected on any browser I could test right now (Chrome, Firefox and Brave on Android). I can already say I wouldn't have been able to find this solution, mostly because I didn't expect the issue to be in the `body` styling to begin with. Thanks a lot again, I mentally accepted I wasn't going to be able to fix it and thought about hacky workarounds, so this is a welcome surprise. I'll do some further reading into the rules and try and maintain them.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all the answer, but the described behavior can be reproduced even on a computer (Ubuntu Linux in my case; *non*-android device) using the given netlify link in Chromium, when using the mobile mode in Chromium DevTools. Maybe by reproducing it this way, somebody gets behind the cause of this behavior.

Upon opening the second folder, the font-size is indeed set to something `42.073px` or something similar, depending on the responsive mode selected in the mobile mode. This is only shown in the "Computed" tab of DevTools, but there is no rule for this size in the "Styles" tab. I don't see any apparent cause for this text size change, sorry.

A few notes, however, on your HTML code (though none of the below seems to solve your problem):

- Better put the `<script>` tag inside the `<body>` tag, right before the closing `</body>`. Or put it inside the `<head>`, but then make sure it get executed after page load. Outside `<body>` or `<head>`, your `<script>` is somewhat in limbo – unexpected side-effects included.
- Similar goes for your `<meta>` tag. Put it inside the `<head>`.
- For valid code and to reduce and even avoid unexpected side effects, surround your complete HTML code with an `<html>` tag, and define a doctype, e.g. `<!doctype html>` at the beginning of your HTML. Validate your HTML, for example here: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Well first of all, thanks for answering, it's reassuring to see someone can see/recreate my issue, I was starting to be afraid it was only a local problem or something. Also thanks for the tips regarding html formatting, I'll change it on my site, as this is surely a better way to do things. I'll have to admit that I was of the mindset of "if it works it's good enough" so far, so these hints are appreciated.